# Can you call an instance method in an ARel query? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to use an instance method(?) in a DB query. If I had an instance method in my class that checked if fields are non-nil

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

   def is_completed?
      return !!(field_1 && field_2 && field_3)
   end
end
```

Can I somehow use that in an AR query? I want to do something like

```
Foo.where(is_completed?: true)
```

The other option I can think of is to keep a separate column `is_completed` in the model and update that based on `is_completed?`, but that seems rather circuitous.

Comment: you can not do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scopes:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :is_completed?, lambda { where.not(field1: [nil, ""], field2: [nil, ""], field3: [nil, ""])  }
end
```

For integers/floats/non-string types, check only for `nil` (and not `""`) or else you will get an empty Relation.

Then you can use it like this.

```
 Foo.is_completed?
```

Comment: It's giving me a `ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block`

Comment: @Richard I have updated the answer. Scopes should be a one liner.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Also note for integers and non-string types, you MUST only check for nil (and not "") or else it will return you an empty relation. I've updated your answer to reflect that.

Comment: You can set the conditions in the array depending on the field types.

Answer (score 0):

Use scope for these kind of queries,Check for non empty fields.

```
scope :is_completed?, ->{ where.not("field1 is null and field2 is null and field3 is null") }
```

Thn use,

```
Foo.is_completed?
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for non-string types? I'm using Postgres and it's throwing me a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "" LINE 1: ..._profiles".* FROM "tutor_profiles" WHERE (rate <> '' or scho...`